# Initial view controller unresponsive with no errors in console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Title says it all...  The initial view controller that I am using is the login/signup view controller and it is unresponsive/crashes with no errors in the console.. The project builds flawlessly with no errors or warnings in the initial view controller.  None of the buttons or the text fields on the view controller can be pressed or accessed.  If you need more information or details on the issue, I can gladly upload it and edit this post.  But any help right now would be appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show me what you have done sofar?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't accidentally unselected `User Interaction Enabled` for any of your `views`?

This will cause the appointed `view` and any of its `subviews` to ignore any incoming `touch events`.

[image]